# Cypress: Find web element and extract text

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

How to find WebElement is exists in DOM or not. If exists then only needs to extract the number and Parse it else parse it as 0. This code is not working as expected.

```
const $result = await cy.find("#WebElementID");
if($result.length > 0)
   cy.get(#WebElementID).should('not.be.null').Invoke('text').then((text)=> { var ElementTextValue = parseInt(text.trim()) });
else
   var ElementTextValue = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether the element exists or not you can use:

```js
cy.get("#WebElementID").should('exist')
cy.get("#WebElementID").should('not.exist')
```

If you want to check whether the element is visible or not and then do actions, you use the Jquery length method, but with this method, you won't get the retry-ability of cypress assertions -

```js
if ($('#WebElementID').length > 0) {
  //Do some thing when element exists
} else {
  //Do something when element doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with jQuery (Cypress.$),

```js
const $result = Cypress.$("#WebElementID")

if ($result.length > 0) {
  cy.get(#WebElementID).should('not.be.null').invoke('text')
    .then((text)=> { 
      const elementTextValue = parseInt(text.trim()) 
      cy.wrap(elementTextValue).as('elementTextValue')  // better strategy
    })
  } else {
    cy.wrap(0).as('elementTextValue')
  }
}

// Get alias, better for async command calls
cy.get('@elementTextValue').then(elementTextValue => {
  // do something with that value in here
})
```